# Casting a value in a dictionary from str to float

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have been trying to look at other questions and not found anything that works for me. I have a list if dictionaries (trips) and want to access the values in each dictionary within the list of trips, and convert if from a string to a float.

If i take trips[0] output is:

```
# {'pickup_latitude': '40.64499',
#  'pickup_longitude': '-73.78115',
#  'trip_distance': '18.38'}
```

I am trying to build a function that iterates through the list of dictionaries, accessing the values and transferring them to floats.

I have tried various versions of the code below, including trying to build a new dictionary and returning that

```
def float_values(trips):
    for trip in trips:
        for key, value in trip.items():
            value = float(value)
        return
```

float_values[0] should output:

```
# {'pickup_latitude': 40.64499,
#  'pickup_longitude': -73.78115,
#  'trip_distance': 18.38}
```

Continuously getting

> 'function' object is not subscriptable'

OR

> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `'function' object is not subscriptable'`:- Most probably you would be using  `float_values[0]` instead of `float_values()[0]`. `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` - Your function is returning None and you are trying to index the `None` object.

Comment: You are not returning anything from that function

Comment: When you use a bare `return` then a reference to `None` is returned by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you what to override your values from the dictionary you should do something like this

```
def float_values(trips):

    for trip in trips:
        for key, value in trip.items():
            trip[key] = float(value)

    return trips
```

By doing `value = float(value)` you are writing temporary the float value and not saving it anywhere

Comment: The `new_trips` list is totally useless - you're modifying the `trip` dicts in place so the initial list will reflect those updates as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply what you need to do is change value inside the dictionary:

```
for list_dict in list_of_dicts:
    for key, value in list_dict.items():
        list_dict[key] = float(value)
```